# Using Jenkins pipeline, running a jar file in background using nohup does not launch the jar

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, macos-high-sierra

I am using Jenkins version  2.121.1 with Pipeline On MacOS-HighSierra.
My project has a dependency on the login server, which is a Springboot artifact, being running locally which I would like to launch before the build. I've a shell script to launch the login server. The shell script works fine from command line. When I run the same in Jenkins' context, it fails. Here is the code in the runloginserver shell script:

```
nohup java -jar /absolute/path/login-module/login-api.jar >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

And in my Jenkinsfile I've defined the stage as follows:

```
stage('Launch-login') {
  steps {
   script{
      withEnv(['JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontkill']) {

        sh '/absolute/path/runloginserver '

       }           
   }
 }

}
```

Console output has no errors. No nohup.out generated. And the server has not been launched

Answer (score -1):

You may be running into the [Jenkins ProcessTree Killer](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller).  This is a Jenkins "feature" that kills any background processes started during a build when the build finishes, even if the process was started with nohup or otherwise dissociated from its parent process.  There are instructions in the link on how to disable this behavior - it can either be disabled globally or just for a specific process.

Comment: No, I am aware of ProcessTree Killer. If you look at the code I shared, I am already handling it.  JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE. Problem is that application is not getting kicked off at all. No errors and no logs. Any other ideas?